# Git Rewrites all lines in a file?

Tags: git, git-status

I'm trying to figure out why **sometimes** git erases a whole file in a commit, and then rewrites all lines, all over again.

When that happens, we are not able to locate all changes correctly.

Example:

Original file:

`hello world`

Then I add a new line:

(The correct behaviour of git would be:)

`hello world
+ This is a new line`

But sometimes we experience this in a commit:

`-hello world
 +hello world
 +This is a new line`

In this example, there are only two lines, so its easy to figure out what happened.
But this happens with files that are large.

What could be the cause of this behaviour? 
Also, in the same commit, there can be correct files (in which git recognizes only the lines that were changed) and incorrect ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is tracking **whitespace** or **line ending** changes as well. So probably one of your "invisible" characters changed.

Sometimes git shows this as well if at first your file didn't have a final newline character and then you added one; like this:

```
-line
\ No newline at end of file
+line
```

Comment: That could very well be the case, but what would be a way of correcting this issue? Changing line end configurations?

Comment: that's a whole other topic; very compliated matter... first you should find out what is the real cause: line endings or whitespace... are you using linux and windows mixed,...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `git diff` or `git show` to view these diffs, try adding the `-w` parameter to ignore all whitespace changes.  This way, you can get the affect that you're looking for when viewing diffs.

for example:

```
git diff -w

git show -w
```